# JavaFX TitledPane remove mouse hover

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] ar){

    launch(ar);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("", null);
    titledPane.setCollapsible(false);
    titledPane.setContent(new javafx.scene.control.TextArea("George"));

    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid;" +
                "-fx-border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);" +
                "-fx-border-width: 1px;");

        titledPane.lookup(".content").setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid;" +
                "-fx-border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);" +
                "-fx-border-width: 1px;");

    });

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Text textTitle = new Text("CONSOLE");
    Button buttonClear = new Button("CLEAR");

    HBox.setMargin(textTitle, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(textTitle, buttonClear);

    titledPane.setGraphic(hBox);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(titledPane));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

[image]

If I place mouse in zone with red line, it trigger mouseover effect of button clear.

How to stop to trigger mouseover effect of button if I'm not with mouse on it?

Comment: What is `content` in the first line of the code you posted?

Comment: @Abra it's an TextArea

Comment: So can I replace it with `new javafx.scene.control.TextArea("George")` ?

Comment: @Abra actually no. I update my code.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, although my GUI looks different to what you posted. The `CLEAR` button **only** changes color when the mouse pointer is over it. Perhaps you can post a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Abra I changed the code sample. If you simply copy paste the entire code it should reproduce my problem and also GUI need to looks like in image.

Comment: I believe TitledPanes make their entire top side an interactive collapse button.  Why not just create an HBox to hold your label and button, and put it in the top area of a BorderPane?

Comment: Have you tried setting CSS for `buttonClear` separately? I mean set the CSS for `titledPane` as you have done in the code you posted, and also explicitly set CSS for `buttonClear`.

Comment: @Abra I tried and same problem. The problem is that title hover trigger also button hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `title` is hovered over, `modena.css` changes a [looked-up color's](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) value to give it the hover style; specifically, it changes `-fx-color`. This appears to have the side-effect of making the `Button` change to its hover style as well. I expect this could be considered a bug.

To work around this problem, apply the following CSS (selectors assume the `Button` is the graphic):

```css
.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button {
    -fx-color: -fx-base;
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button:hover {
    -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button:armed {
    -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
}
```

The above will make the `Button` keep its default styling. You can obviously style the `Button` your own way using the same selectors.

Since you need to target pseudo classes it will be easier to have the CSS in an external file, rather than setting the styles inline with `setStyle`. To keep the look you have, you can use the following stylesheet (includes the above):

```css
.titled-pane {
    -fx-collapsible: false;
    -fx-content-display: right;
    -fx-graphic-text-gap: 10px;
}

.titled-pane > .title,
.titled-pane > .content {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button {
    -fx-color: -fx-base;
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button:hover {
    -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover > .button:armed {
    -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
}
```

And here's an example using this CSS:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var pane = new TitledPane("CONSOLE", new TextArea("This is the console output."));
        pane.setGraphic(new Button("CLEAR"));

        var scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Main.css"); // replace with your resource

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I prefer to use setStyle because it not require addition file for my simple app which I want to be just one jar and nothing else. Also how I can translate `title:hover > .button` for `setStyle`?

Comment: The CSS file would be a resource, which means it should be bundled _inside_ the JAR file upon deployment. Doing this manually in code will be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks for solution and advice. P.S.: First time it didn't worked, but I removed `>` from css and now works.

Comment: The `>` means the next selector only applies to direct children, not having it will apply the styles to all matching descendants (I believe). Note that I have the `Button` as the graphic of the `TitledPane` instead of your `HBox`. To put it to the right of the text, I set the `contentDisplay` to `RIGHT` (in CSS). Remember, `TitledPane` is a `Labeled`.